# How to obtain parameters from a statement in Roslyn to variable

Tags: c#, roslyn

So far I've been able to find Console.WriteLine("Hello World") statement inside the method.body. But I want to also collect "Hello World" string to from WriteLine("Hello World"); statement. How I can do this? My Code:

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax method = syntaxTree.GetRoot()
                                           .DescendantNodes()
                                           .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                                           .First();
BlockSyntax statement = method.Body;
ControlFlowAnalysis controlFlow = semanticModel.AnalyzeControlFlow(statement);
StatementSyntax state = statement.Statements.First();

Console.WriteLine(state.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I got inside my syntax tree Console.WriteLine("Hello World") statement and it will find it and store it to state. I need to get that statement arguments too not the whole statement. So I could example store string for other purposes.

Comment: You should put a breakpoint on your `Console.WriteLine` line, and inspect `state`.  Presumably it's an `ExpressionStatementSyntax`.  Inspect it in the debugger, look at the `Expression` property, and drill down until you find your string.